# How to get this using css3?

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, transform, translate

I want this animation in my fontAwesome icon's border. I have tried a lot but failed.

Here is the animation.

http://postimg.org/image/8k3al48kr/

Comment: How about some code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpqbv1f2/

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996110/progress-bar-along-the-borders-of-a-rectangle/32003052) and it should help you.

Comment: @harry Thanks for your reply. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do it with only one HTML element but the following should work:

```css
.square {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.left, .top, .right, .bottom {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: black;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
.left, .right {
    -moz-animation-name: drawVertical;
    -webkit-animation-name: drawVertical;
    -o-animation-name: drawVertical;
    animation-name: drawVertical;
    width: 1px;
}
.top, .bottom {
    -moz-animation-name: drawHorizontal;
    -webkit-animation-name: drawHorizontal;
    -o-animation-name: drawHorizontal;
    animation-name: drawHorizontal;
    height: 1px;
}
.left {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
}
.top {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
.right {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 1px;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
@keyframes drawHorizontal {
    from {
        width: 0;
    }
    to {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@keyframes drawVertical {
    from {
        height: 0;
    }
    to {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
    <span class="left"></span>
    <span class="top"></span>
    <span class="right"></span>
    <span class="bottom"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I pretty much knew it is the only solution.But I thought it would be the bad practice.

But Thanks a lot for your help, I learned some new stuff from your solution .

Comment: @AshrafulHaque there's also a way to use a sprite and CSS keyframes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178499/how-to-show-parts-of-sprite-with-css-keyframes-to-create-animation but that involves doing an additional HTTP request to get the image.

Comment: @AshrafulHaque You can also animate/draw SVG but I've never tried it.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I will follow your instruction.